# gzip failing for `.min.js` files, but fine for all others including `.js`

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

Im using the following in a .htaccess file to enable gzip

```
#GZIP
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

It seems to work, but its not gzipping this file :

```
http://example.co.uk/dist/js/bundle.min.js
```

Any idea why this wouldnt be, isnt this read by the server as a normal js file as it ends with .js ?